# Reading JSON with Boost property_tree

Tags: c++, json, boost

I'm trying to use Boost's `property tree` to parse a JSON-file. Here is the JSON-file

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": [{
        "b_a": 2,
        "b_b": {
            "b_b_a": "test"
        },
        "b_c": 0,
        "b_d": [{
            "b_d_a": 3,
            "b_d_b": {
                "b_d_c": 4
            },
            "b_d_c": "test",
            "b_d_d": {
                "b_d_d": 5
            }
        }],
        "b_e": null,
        "b_f": [{
            "b_f_a": 6
        }],
        "b_g": 7
    }],
    "c": 8
}
```

and a MWE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    boost::property_tree::ptree jsontree;
    boost::property_tree::read_json("test.json", jsontree);

    int v0 = jsontree.get<int>("a");
    int v1 = jsontree.get<int>("c");
}
```

**Question** I currently know how to read the outermost variables `a` and `c`. However, I'm having difficulty reading other levels such as `b_a, b_b_a, b_d_a` and so on. How can I do this with Boost? I'm not necessarily looking for a solution involving loops, merely trying to figure out how to "extract" inner variables.

I am open to using other libraries if they are optimal. But so far Boost looks promising to me.

Comment: You can use "." separator to specify path to nested nodes like `jsontree.get<string>("b.b_b.b_b_a")`

Comment: For JSON, I'd generally recommend one of two possibilities. If you're doing something like a REST server that needs to operate on *massive* amounts of JSON as fast as humanly possible, you want [RapidJSON](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson). For nearly everything else, you probably want [Nlohmann's JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

Comment: @zett42 I tried it out, I get an error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path> >'
  what():  No such node (b.b_b.b_b_a)`

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks, I like that Nlohmann's JSON library is easily added to a project. I'm missing a bunch of examples though to figure out how to parse my file, I didn't find any useful at the main site

Comment: Using Nlohmann's library, retrieving `b_d_a` would be something like: `json j = json::parse(input_string); std::cout << j["b"]["b_d"]["b_d_a"];`

Comment: You got the error because I missed the fact that child node `b` is an array. See my answer.

Comment: @Jerry I think you would need something like `j["b"][0]["b_d"][0]["b_d_a"]` because both `b` and `b_d` are arrays. I don't know if this syntax is valid though.

Comment: @zett42: Oh, quite right (I didn't read the JSON carefully enough). And yes, what you wrote should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get nested elements you can use the path syntax where each path component is separated by `"."`. Things are a little bit more complicated here because the child node `b` is an array. So you can't do without a loop.

```
const pt::ptree& b = jsontree.get_child("b");
for( const auto& kv : b ){
    cout << "b_b_a = " << kv.second.get<string>("b_b.b_b_a") << "\n";    
}
```

[Live demo at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a203c473c0c60fa7)

I've also added code to print the whole tree recursively so you can see how the JSON gets translated to the ptree. Arrays elements are stored as key/value pairs where the key is an empty string.